# Flutter app receiving multiple notifications when app is opened

Tags: flutter, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using firebase messaging API. Background and terminated messages are working fine but when app is opened i get double or triple notifications

I tried commenting local notification display function but then it doesnt display any notification